# comparing two columns with wordlist and highlighting differences in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, neo4j, display

I'm trying to create a function to audit access rights between accounts. The data are provided by a neo4j database.
What I want to achieve is to compare line by line, two cells, the one in the columns 4 and the other in 8. I also want to highlight the differences. These cells contain a list of words (access rights) like this:

```
ID| User A | ROLES | Rights | SOME INFO | USER B| ROLES | RIGHTS 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1 | titi   | Reader|[a,b,d] | blalbalbla| toto  | writer|[c,d,f,a]
------------------------------------------------------------------
2 | tata   | Manage|[b,f,g] | blalblalba| tutu  | Reader|[a,b,d]
```

I want to comparer titi's rights with toto's rights and tata with tutu and highlight the one that differs.

My function is :

```
def _render_results(self, queries):
    num_queries = len(queries)
    # For each selected query
    for counter, q in enumerate(queries, 1):
        # Print result
        if q['result']:
            df = pandas.DataFrame(q['result'])
            # Replace header
            df = df[1:]
            df.columns = q['headers']
            # Table settings
            pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', 500000)
            pandas.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 0)
            display(df)  
        else:
            self.printmd("No Results !")
```

I use the display function to render, but I can't find a way to compare and highlight. Any idea how to achieve that ?

Comment: please provide your DataFrame in a reproducible format: `df.to_dict('list')`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers and help. I want to display the dataframe as a table and any rights in user B's cell that are not the same as the rights in user A's cell should be highlighted (or colored). I don't know if it's possible as if with the display() function...  The code is used in a Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is the solution you are looking for.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2],
                 'User A': ['titi', 'tata'],
                 'ROLES1': ['Reader', 'Manage'],
                 'Rights': [['a','b','d'], ['b','f','g']],
                 'SOME INFO': ['blalbalbla', 'blalbalbla'],
                 'USER B': ['tutu', 'toto'],
                 'ROLES2': ['writer', 'reader'],
                 'RIGHTS': [['c','d','f','a'], ['a','b','d']]})

df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x['Rights']) - set(x['RIGHTS'])), axis = 1)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers and help. With your solution, I can see the rights that USER B doesn't have compared to the rights of USER A and create a new 'diff' column with this information. This is great and a first step for me :-). I'm going to dig deeper, because what I want to do is to color or highlight in the rights cells the rights (for each user) that USER B has and USER A does not and the rights that USER A has and B does not. I use this code ins a Jupyter Notebook, so I think I should use an HTML render to achieve that.